# What do all of the different Detached [insert string]Element mean in a Heap Snapshot

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to fix some memory issues in my react app so I have been taking heap snapshots to see what is being added and taken away. Whenever I read anything about finding memory leaks/bloat they mainly speak about `Detached DOM Tree` and that they should be removed as much as possible. I am not showing `Detached DOM Tree` but I am showing 12 other `Detached` Elements:

```
Detached CSSStyleDeclaration
Detached HTMLAnchorElement
Detached HTMLButtonElement
Detached HTMLDivElement
...
```

1. Should I be concerned about these from a performance stand point? (I would assume yes)
2. How do I go about figuring out what the actual element is and tracing it back to remove it? When I drop down any of these values I just see a ton of information that I am not sure how to decipher.

Below is a screen shot of difference between two snapshots showing all of the Detached Elements.

[image]

Comment: I think you'll have to analyze and tweak your code because there's no way to backtrack those detached DOM nodes meaningfully.